# Is there a transient kind of annotation for Spring-data-mongodb

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I just changed my springboot from using Postgresql to mongo, i am trying to get the mongodb to leave out a property when storing an object in MongoDB, but the @Transient field doesnt work. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

`@Transient` is supposed to work with Spring Data MongoDB.

From [the Spring Data MongoDB documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html/):

> `@Transient`: By default all private fields are mapped to the document,
>   this annotation excludes the field where it is applied from being
>   stored in the database

If it isn't working for you, I suggest including your code in your question.

Note that if you forgot to add `@Transient` and added some data to your database, then later added `@Transient` to a field, Spring Data Mongo isn't going to go through the database collection and delete that field from all the documents that currently have it, it just won't include that field in any new documents it saves to the collection.